# Tuning Spacy 2.0 textcat for multilabel

Tags: nlp, text-classification, spacy, multilabel-classification

I am developing a multilabel document classifier for use with ~300 labels that have substantial overlap. I have been experimenting with Spacy 2.0's textcat for this purpose, training a single textcat pipe for multilabel prediction. It is giving some promising results, but the scoring tends to score a single label very heavily or none at all.

It seems I'll be able to get very accurate, independent scores per label with a binary relevance approach, but training and deploying 300+ models may have some practical drawbacks.

I've tried tuning the dropout in the single classifier approach, to limited effect.

What parameters tunings or other changes can I make to get textcat to be more optimistic and less exclusive in its scoring?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Was your training data balanced, i.e. did you train it with similar number of samples per label?